# Inheriting looping variable or local, global macros

Tags: stata, stata-macros

`main.do` is:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {

do run.do

}
```

and `run.do`  is:

```
foreach y in y1 y2{ 
reg `y' x
outreg2 using `y'.xls, append ctitle(`mode')

}
```

It has `outreg2`, so it produced a txt output. But I found that the column title is empty meaning that Stata couldn't get `mode`.

That implies that the `mode` loop in `main.do` was not inherited by `run.do`.

How can I make it inherited? It would be wonderful if I could choose whether   to make it inherited.

What I tried is:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
global mode `mode'
do run.do
}
```

and:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
local mode `mode'
do run.do
}
```

and:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
global mode "`mode'"
do run.do
}
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Local and global macros are not considered to be variables in Stata. Naturally, they correspond loosely to entities called variables elsewhere, but Stata use is strict and statistical: a variable in Stata is (and is only) a column in a dataset. See e.g. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html for more discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local macros are .... local. meaning visible only within the same interactive session, program, do-file, or (chunk of) code in a do-file editor window.

Globals are a crude solution to making stuff visible everywhere, but you must refer to them as such using `$`. So in your `run.do` you would need

```
ctitle($mode)
```

Passing the contents as arguments is a much better solution.

See also the help for `include`.

All this is utterly basic Stata programming. To become competent as a Stata programmer, a minimal reference is https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf, which is also bundled with Stata on your system (unless your version is several years out of date).

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippets demonstrate @Nick's excellent advice in the context of your example.

#### 1. Change `run.do` to call a global instead of a local macro:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
    global mode `mode'
    do run.do
}

foreach y in y1 y2 { 
    reg `y' x
    outreg2 using `y'.xls, append ctitle($mode)
}

macro drop mode
```

#### 2. Convert `run.do` into a program and pass local macro `mode` as argument:

```
program define foo
foreach y in y1 y2{ 
    reg `y' x
    outreg2 using `y'.xls, append ctitle(`1')
}
end

foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
    foo `mode'
}
```

#### 3. `include` the file `run.do` in `main.do` as is:

```
foreach mode in mode1 mode2 {
    include run.do
}
```

The last approach is closer to the 'inheritance' solution you are looking for.